# access all files in folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js

is library versioning is supported in nodeJS?

i have folder like package/version/1.0/
and files under this path 
test1.js
test2.js

```
 script.js
 //access the folder package of version 1.1
 var lib = require('require-all')(__dirname + '/package/version/1.0');

 test1.js
 ========
 function sum()
 { a+b ;}
 exports.sum = sum;

  test2.js
  ========
  function sub()
  { a-b ;}
  exports.sub = sub;
```

in script.js file, can require the package/version/1.1 folder. but how can i access the function sum() and sub() in my script file? and is library versioning supported in nodeJS? is the above code is a sort of library versioning ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i haven't seen versions of libraries in one package, most common way is to release new versions of packages and upload them online, defining the required version in a package.json dependencies , npm will take care of download & install

If you want to deprecate a certain version of your library online there is `npm deprecate` which is the right command for that job.

---

When you create new npm package you can define a `main` script which will handle the loading of all files inside the package.

Usually its called `index.js` or `main.js` and it will be used when someone calls `require('<library>');`

So you can try the following to achieve the "versioning"

`index.js`

```
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path');
var _packageJSON=require(__dirname+'/package.json');
var defaultVersion=_packageJSON.version;
module.exports=function(whichVersion){
 whichVersion=whichVersion||defaultVersion;
 fs.exists(whichVersion,function(_exists){
  if(_exists==null){
   throw new Error('Unable to load version : '+whichVersion+' : '+_packageJSON.name);
  }else{
   // require , 1.0/index.js
   require(path.join(whichVersion,'index.js'));
  } 
 }
}
```

and any script that has that package as dependency it can load it by simply calling

`require("<library name>")(<version>)` ex.
`require("mylib")("1.0")`

under each version inside the package, you can have `index.js` which loads/exports variables and functions properly.

The final structure should look like

- my npm package *main module*

  - `index.js` *file*
  - `versions` *directory*

    - `1.0/index.js` *file*

      - `util.js`
      - `fn.js`
      - `var.js`
    - `2.0/index.js` *file*

      - `util.js`
      - `fn.js`
      - `var.js`

Hope it helps.